# Motion of upright pendulum with negligible initial velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was looking at the following problem (from the 1939 Putnam Exam):

> A weightless rod is hinged at $O$ so that it can rotate without friction in a vertical plane. A mass $m$ is attached to the end of the rod $A$, which is balanced vertically above $O$. At time $t = 0$, the rod moves away from the vertical with negligible initial angular velocity. Prove that the mass first reaches the position under $O$ at $t = \sqrt{OA \over g}\ln(1 + \sqrt{2})$.

If we let $r = OA$ and $\theta$ be the angle the rod makes with the vertical at the top, then by conservation of energy we have ${1\over 2}r^2\dot{\theta}^2 = rg(1 - \cos\theta)$, which leads to the integral

$$
\int_0^\pi {1 \over \sqrt{1 - \cos\theta}} d\theta,
$$

which diverges. But the pendulum definitely reaches the bottom in some finite time. Why do the equations give a seemingly wrong answer for this problem? Or is there some other mistake in this reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that the pendulum reaches the bottom in a finite time is wrong and your calculation is correct: it reaches the top position in infinite time. One way to see this is the non intersecting property of trajectories in phase space: due to the stationary solution at the top, you cannot have a solution reaching the top in finite time with vanishing velocity.

Another way to see this is to calculate the trajectory of the mass. I’ll keep your notations, but set $m=r=g=1$ by choosing convenient units of mass, length, and time, you have the energy:
$$
1=\frac{\dot\theta}{2}+\cos\theta
$$
so starting at $t_0$ at position $\theta_0$:
$$
t-t_0=\int\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}} \\
= \left[\ln \left(\tan \frac{\theta}{4}\right)\right]_{\theta_0}^\theta
$$

Note that the time diverges (logarithmically in the angle) as the point to reach approaches the upper position. I think there is a mistake in your Putnam problem. Going backwards, the time they gave corresponds to the time needed to go from the horizontal position $\theta=\pi/2$ to the bottom $\theta=\pi$.

Btw, a third way to see that the result diverges is by noting that the libration period diverges logarithmically as $E\to1^+$. Mathematically, you have the asymptotic formula for the period:

$$
T\sim -\ln(E-1)
$$

Hope this helps.